# php@docker on production

Tags: php, docker-swarm

В qa кластере, при нагрузочном тестировании php-fpm кушает в 2-3 раза больше CPU чем на голом железе. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

- bases image  - php:7.4-fpm-alpine
- opcache включен, без него совсем плохо
- Yii2 - разница заметна уже после загрузки yii autoloader, но не до.

В целом скорость работы сайта не изменилась - время при прогретом кеше 250-300ms, но cpu...

Есть у кого какие идеи?
Сколько по вашему опыту, были потери при миграции на docker?
Заранее спасибо за ответы